# Change Sharepoint Tenant URL using SharePoint Online Management Shell - abc.sharepoint.com to xyz.sharepoint.com

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365

I'm trying desperately to change the base URL of my Sharepoint Office 365 account.

For example, I need to go from abcCOM.sharepoint.com to abc.sharepoint.com

I am under the impression that I can do this using the SharePoint Online Management Shell, but I can't seem to figure out how. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change a Office365 / MS Azure AD tenant name.

From: [Change your SharePoint domain name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-your-sharepoint-domain-name)

> Unfortunately, it isn't possible to change the SharePoint domain name for your organization in Microsoft 365. For example, if the name of your organization changes from "Contoso" to "Fourth Coffee," you can't change contoso.sharepoint.com to fourthcoffee.sharepoint.com.
>
> To use the domain name fourthcoffee.sharepoint.com, you would need to
> purchase a new Microsoft 365 subscription and move all email, files,
> and any other data you want to keep to the new subscription.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not feasible to change the initial onmicrosoft.com domain after sign-up. To use a different onmicrosoft.com domain, you’d have to start a new subscription. The following article is for your reference:

- [You can't rename your team site URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/domains-faq?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-gb%252farticle%252fAbout-your-initial-onmicrosoft-com-domain-in-Office-365-b9fc3018-8844-43f3-8db1-1b3a8e9cfd5a&view=o365-worldwide#why-do-i-have-an--onmicrosoft-de--domain)

BR